Next.js useRouter navigation with existing query parameters not working on Safari browser
I'm encountering an issue with Next.js useRouter when navigating from a page that already has query parameters on Safari browser.
Here's the problem:
In my Next.js application, I'm using useRouter to handle navigation. 
When the user is already on a page with existing query parameters (e.g., https://localhost:0000/search?market=usa), and tries to navigate to another page using router.push, the navigation fails.
However, this behavior works correctly on other browsers.
Home component
const Home = ({ name }) => {
  const encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(name);

  const queryParam = { market: encodedValue };

  return (
    <Link href={{ pathname: "/search", query: queryParam }} passHref>
    ...

Search page
const SearchPage = ({ decodedValue }) => {
...

  return (
   <>
    {decodedValue}
    </>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { query } = context;
  const decodedValue = decodeURIComponent(query?.market);

  return {
    props: {
      decodedValue,
    },
  };
}

export default SearchPage;

Let me know, please, if i didn't provide enough information or more clarification is needed.
